# How do I enable SSH on Termux for accessing Android Host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, android

I'm just experimenting with compilers in termux for compiling kernels using Ubuntu aarch64 environment, In my experience there is no need for a cross compiler and I felt that having 8 cores (I'm on a Snapdragon 625 mobile), really helps in compile time, but using touchscreen to input commands is a really bad experience, I'm wondering if there is a way to setup an SSH server like OpenSSH server in termux-ubuntu to use the full sized PC keyboard on termux.

Answer (score 1):

sshd

Type sshd in termux and it will start the ssh server